# Openlayers geometry shapes not zooming when map is zoomed

Tags: javascript, geometry, zooming, openlayers

I have drawn a circle geometry with Openlayers and the circle is displayed in map but when i zoom the map the circle doesn't get zoomed and it remains in same radius getting smaller at each zoom out level

I have drawn the circle geometry as per below

```
var circleFeature = new ol.Feature
    ({
      geometry: new ol.geom.Circle([0, 0], 5)
    });

circleStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 5,
          fill: null,
          zIndex: 3,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: '#FF0000',
              width: 2
          })
      })     
    });
```

I expect the circle (or any geometry) to get zoomed as in eg: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html. But in my case it not working so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style it using

```
 new ol.style.Style({
          fill: null,
          zIndex: 3,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: '#FF0000',
              width: 2
          })
    });
```

`ol.style.Circle` is used to style features such as points with a circular image, the radius is in pixels so doesn't change with zoom.

Comment: I have drawn a MultiLineString with style `var PathFeature = new ol.Feature
    ({
      geometry: new ol.geom.MultiLineString(pathCoords)
    });    `   'style = new ol.style.Style
                  ({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke
                    ({
                      color: '#FFFFFF',
                      width: 1,
                      lineDash: [5, 5]
                    })
                  });'  But the line is pixelated on zoom not smooth line

Answer (score 0):

You have added circle as markers so it's not gonna worked.
for your need you need to add circle property class.

try this

```
var centerLongitudeLatitude = ol.proj.fromLonLat([23.0225,72.5714]);
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    features: [new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Circle(centerLongitudeLatitude, 400000))]
  }),
  style: [
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'blue',
        width: 3,
        opacity:0.6,
         brightness: 0.2
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
      })
    })
  ]
});
```

here 400000= 400000 meter